# Directadmin soapclient error

Tags: php, soap, centos, soap-client, directadmin

In server one I user soapclient

```
$GLOBALS['params'] = [
        "where" => $fldpar,

    ];

    $client1 = new soapclient('http://**.**.**.**:3000/Service1.svc?wsdl');

$res = $client1->Read_1522($GLOBALS['params']);
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($res), True);


$xml = simplexml_load_string($arr['Read_1522Result']['any']);
 $json = json_encode($xml);


 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

config server one is:centos , directadmin,php56

and in server to i have ssl and install soap but when use soapcliene this has error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://**.**.**.**:3000/Service1.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://**.**.**.**:3000/Service1.svc?wsdl" in /home/ht2net/domains/****/public_html/ab/index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /home/ht2net/domains/******/public_html/ab/index.php(26): SoapClient-
```

whats the problem?

Comment: Does that file (the wsdl) exist? Is remote access allowed? What happens if you try to load it directly in your browser?

Comment: yes it online and when open in browser loaded .